# Error during CI 3.0.1 to CI 3.1.9 upgrading?

Tags: php, odbc, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3.0.1 version for long. (3 years without upgradation)
I have 
a) php 5.4.3 , 
b) informix database
c) and odbc connectivity to informix say (eadmin)

As of now i have connection in config/database.php as follows 
(i.e. in CI 3.0.1)

```
$db['default'] = array( 
    'dsn'   => 'eadmin',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => ''
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'eadmin'
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

My project was super smooth.
In my model, I used to make queries using

```
$rows = $this->db->select('perno, name')
    ->where('grade','10')
    ->get('employees');
$data = $rows->result_array();
var_dump($data);
```

I was able to get the result and process perfectly.

The issue is, now I upgraded the CI version 3.1.9 and I kept the same connection parameters as above. But the above query build fails.
It says method not found. Further whatever method I am giving after `$this->db->` gives an error on that line.

e.g.

```
$this->db->query("select perno, name from employees");
$this->db->get('employees');
```

etc give an error.

I tested with Oracle also but gave error as above.
Kindly note that I am using ODBC driver.

What must I do? Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer to the problem on [this page of upgrade instructions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_310.html). If I understand it correctly, it says that if you're using odbc you cannot use Query Builder.

There may be a third-party informix driver for CodeIgniter out in the wild somewhere. A little Google time should help you find it.

CI recommends PHP version 5.6 or newer. That's probably not a "show stopper" but would be wise to do if you can.